# Magento 2 Free Shipping Over 499 Excluding some product

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I am integrating shipping conditions in my website.Currently it Flat rate is enabled with 140 Rs per order and it is working fine.Also I have created one cart rule coupon type where condition is if order more than 499 then shipping cost should free.Everything working fine.

Now there is a condition where looking a condition that some brand product have shipping cost and if these items are in cart than there should be extra price same as Amazon shipping.

So how to integrate shipping method that fulfill both condition if order is above 499 then shipping cost should free and if cart item have brand items that who have extra shipping cost.

Please give me an idea to fulfill this condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the documentation for promotions/cart price rules - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html. The rules are flexible in that you can create promotions for only specific categories or down to the product level. I found that there is a bit of trial and error to learning what can be done.

NOTES:

- You may need to turn on some configurations for promotions to get to
  the SKU level
- Some promotions require a carrier module to work properly. There is a config at a high level but some of the logic exists in the carrier module.
- Version is important. I am working in 2.2.10 currently and have found that some of the feature are flaky. Hoping 2.3.X is better